# can I implement select_or_other just with core form API?

Tags: 7, forms

[Select (or other)](http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other) works great but I want know can I implement its functionality with `invisible` key available for #states attribute described in [form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#select)

Comment: There is no `invisible` attribute, do you mean the `invisible` option for the `#title_display` or the `invisible` key available for `#states`?

Comment: yes, I mean key available for #states, question edited.

Comment: Yes, yes you can. It would require quite a bit of tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that with FAPI & #states.

You would do something like this:

```
$form['options'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select'),
  '#options' => array(
    'one' => t('One'),
    'two' => t('Two'),
    'three' => t('Three'),
    'other' => t('Other'),
  ),
);
$form['other'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Other'),
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
     ':input[name="options"]' => array('value' => 'other'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

This would make the "other" field visible when the value of the "options" field is "other".

For more info on states see the docs for [drupal_process_states()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7)